# How to disable an input field if it has value in blade.php

Tags: php, laravel-blade, disabled-input

I am trying to disabled an input field if it has value. Somehow, it looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="sex" value="{{ old('sex', $user['sex']) }}" placeholder="">
```

I have tried adding like:

```
<input type="text" name="sex" value="{{ old('sex', $user['sex']) }}" 
  disabled= {{ $user['sex'] == null ? disabled :'' }}  >
```

But it is not working. I am using blade.php by the way.

Comment: Can you use javascript or jQuery ?

Comment: If you can, try this :
 $(documet).ready(function () {
         if ($(".yourInput").val() !== "") {
                $(".yourInput").setAttribute("disabled");
         }
}

Comment: @Hema_Elmasry Unfortunately I can't use. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
  <input type="text" name="sex" value="{{ old('sex', $user['sex']) }}" {{ $user['sex'] ? '' : 'disabled' }}  >
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have just added `$user['sex'] == '' ` to make it work well :)

Answer (score 1):

By disabling the field it breaks the validation rules. I would rather prefer using readonly attribute.

```
<input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" {{ $role->name ? 'readonly' : '' }} value="{{ old('name', $role->name) }}"  required="true" aria-required="true"/>
```